# How to sort two different date columns in mysql in descending order?

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me on how to sort two different date columns in mysql?

I have created a query using a table with two different columns. The first is the cert_date and the other one is the special_training_date_from. What i want to do is when I execute the query, the output must be like this: The cert_date and special_training_date_from columns must be sorted together in descending order. For instance if the cert_date are '2012-01-03, 2012-07-07' and the special_training_date_from are '2011-05-03, 2013-08-01', the output must be:

```
    2013-08-01,
    2012-07-07,
    2012-01-03,
    2011-05-03
```

This is the query that I've used.

```
Select training_title, cert_date, special_training_date_from 
from tabletraining 
order by cert_date + sptrain_from desc;
```

The result is correct everytime I sort it in ascending order, but I want to sort it in descending order and everytime I put the 'desc' keyword, the result becomes incorrect.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you post some sample data and the full output you would expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the dates in a single column to use `order by`:

```
select training_title, thedate, which
from ((Select training_title, cert_date as thedate, 'cert' as which
       from tabletraining
      ) union all
      (select training_title, special_training_date_from, 'special' as which
       from tabletraining
      )
     ) t
order by thedate desc;
```

EDIT:

If you just want the distinct dates in the two columns, then use:

```
select distinct thedate
from ((Select training_title, cert_date as thedate, 'cert' as which
       from tabletraining
      ) union all
      (select training_title, special_training_date_from, 'special' as which
       from tabletraining
      )
     ) t
order by thedate desc;
```

Comment: @Jessa . . . No, I just added it in to say where the data came from.  It is not necessary to get the dates.  The use here is as a column alias.

Comment: Sir, I got confused with the word 'cert' and 'special'.

Comment: Sir I have tried your suggestion but the result was duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
order by CONCAT(cert_date,sptrain_from) desc;
```